# How to add different text after the map function has rendered 3 times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I want to add some text after the cards have rendered three times. these cards take value from a local json file using split and map. i also want to change the text every three times the component has rendered.

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data.json';
import { Card,Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Med() {
    
    return (
        <div>
                {data.slice(0,6).map((item)=>{
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title>{item.Name}</Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Text>
                                        This is the explaination of product card.
                                    </Card.Text>
                                    <Button variant="primary">Add to cart</Button>
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Card>                           
                        </div>   
                    )
                    
                })}       
        </div>
    )
}

export default Med;
```

[This is my current output. but I want it to display some text after chris's card.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srqel.png)

Comment: map also takes more parameters, one of which is an index `map((item,idx))` so you can make use of `idx >2`

Comment: It's probably not JSON if you can `slice` and `map` over it without parsing it first. You should add a [mcve] including the data, and your expected output, to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`{data.slice(0,6).map((item,index)=>{//use the index to conditionally render })}`

Edit #1 -
So, after reading your comment maybe this code will give you an idea

```
{data.slice(0, 6).map((item, index) => {
return (
 <div>
   {index < 3 ? <h1>First three</h1> : <h1>From Fourth</h1>
 </div>
);
})}
```

Comment: I actually considered doing this. But was not successful doing so. i couldn't get the if condition to work inside the div component. sorry if I'm being dumb. I'm actually new to react js.

Comment: Can you send that approach.?

Comment: I can't use if condition inside Return. how do I create a conditional statement inside return.

Comment: @redwing have a look at the edit

Comment: missing a closing `}`?

Comment: @Tarun yes it did work. but this prints First three after every card component. But I wanted it to print First three only once after the third component.